# utf8 conver gb2312 garbled

Tags: php, vb.net

I read a chinese string from php to VB.net, these is partial code

```php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
...
echo "测试用";
...
```

then read from vb.net:

```php
Dim Str() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(chinese_string)
Dim newStr() As Byte = Encoding.Convert(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, System.Text.Encoding.Default, Str)
Dim strUTF8 As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newStr)
```

the output string is："测试�?.."
but when I echo "测试用的", it can show normal.
if the string count is odd, it will occur garbled,but even is normal.

Comment: That code doesn't really make sense to me. You start with a `String` and you convert that to `Bytes` using the UTF8 encoding. So far so good. You then convert those `Bytes` from a UTF8 encoded-representation of the original `String` to a representation using the default encoding. Still OK. Finally, you take the `Bytes` that represent the `String` in the default encoding and try to convert them to a `String` using the UTF8 encoding.  Why would you expect that last step to do anything useful?

Comment: if direct reading or use Encoding.GetEncoding("GB2312").GetString(newBy1)  I got "浼佷笟鐗?"

Comment: What is `chinese_string`? How do you get it?. An UTF-8 encoded string can be directly passed to a `TextBox.Text` property without any encoding in between. Even if the TextBox current font doesn't support those characters.

Comment: I get from mysql, and the mysql charset is utf8 too

Comment: 'mysqli_set_charset( $con , "utf8" );    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserID = '$userid' ORDER BY ID ";          if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))   echo $row['Name'] ."\n";

Comment: if I can modify php to echo iconv("UTF-8","GBK",$row['Name']) , get direct from php it will show normal , for some reason,  I can not modify the php files, just can modify the VB.NET clent.